# Is there anyway to get .mp4 and .png url of pinterest pins?

Tags: java, android

Im going to make an pinterest downloader app with android studio. Does anyone know how to get url of pins ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the public API : https://developers.pinterest.com/